# AIVA- Expected number of IO clients failed to join in time

Tags: python, chatbot

I have an AIVA chatbot integrated with my application, which is not responding to the queries. Below are the logs generated out of it.

Once the application servers are restarted the chatbot is up for sometime and eventually fails again to work. Any help?

> ```
>     * nohup npm start to start up the chatbot server *
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] Authenticated database successfully
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO Starting aiva process
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO Starting poly-socketio server on port: 6467, expecting 4 IO clients
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] ERROR
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] ERROR
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] ERROR
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:44 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO Deploying bot aivadev with adapter HTTPADAPTER
>     Starting up aivadev
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:46 GMT+0000 (utc)] WARNING Expected /data/installations/aiva/aiva-IAE/aiva/scripts/server.config to assign a function to module.exports, got object
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:46 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO global-client-js 1oK8mIFqpNepxpcQAABo joined, -101 remains
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:31:46 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO All`enter code here` 4 IO clients have joined
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:33:24 GMT+0000 (utc)] ERROR {}
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:33:24 GMT+0000 (utc)] ERROR Expected number of IO clients failed to join in time
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:33:24 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO Shutting down
>     [Mon Apr 15 2019 07:33:24 GMT+0000 (utc)] INFO 1oK8mIFqpNepxpcQAABo left
>     error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
>     error: Script restart attempt #1
> ```